# MVC reload issue with dropdownlistfor onchange ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My DropDownListFor looks like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.CampaignID,
        new SelectList(Model.Campaigns, "ID", "Name"),
        "---Geen---",
        new {
            id = "campaignDdl",
            data_url = Url.Action("CampaignChosen", "Nomination")
        }
    )
```

My onchange javascript looks like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#campaignDdl').change(function () {
        //alert('Template knop geklikt');
        var $campaignDdl = $('#campaignDdl');
        var selCampID = $campaignDdl.val();
        var url = $campaignDdl.data('url');
        $.post(url, { selectedCampaignID: selCampID }, function (data) {
            $('#campaign').html(data);
        })
    .fail(function (jqxhr) { alert(JSON.stringify(jqxhr)); });
    });
});
```

My CampaignChosen action looks like:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult CampaignChosen(string selectedCampaignID) {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCampaignID)) {
            int campaignID = Convert.ToInt32(selectedCampaignID);
            Models.Campaign campaign = Models.Campaign.GetCampaignByID(campaignID);

            return PartialView("ShowCampaignOverview", campaign);
        } else {
            return PartialView("ShowCampaignOverview", null);
        }

    }
```

As you can see I'm passing a partial view. The javascript makes sure the view get's put in a div with an id = "campaign". This div is defined under the dropdownlistfor you saw earlier, like so:

```
<div id="campaign"></div>
```

When an item is selected everything works fine. Couldn't be happier. But when you press reload on the browser the selected item is still shown in the dropdownlistfor, but I have no idea how to load the proper partial view in that div again. Because I'm still a bit new to MVC.

Can anybody point out how this is usually done in MVC? Thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: didn't quite get your problem ..the dropdown stays populated with the old values (that where added via the onchange) when you reload the page ?  See: cache, outputcache, or you want to repopulate the dropdown from scratch when the page is refreshed ? See: page.onload, instead of ele.onchange event

Comment: Well apparantly the problem is so simple that there really isn't a problem. Sorry for bothering you with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of $.post()
Regarding that put new load code chunk into function and call onece when page loads and once when event is tirggered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#campaignDdl').change(function () {
      loadCampaignById();
    .fail(function (jqxhr) { alert(JSON.stringify(jqxhr)); });
    });

   loadCampaignById();
});

function loadCampaignById()
{
   var $campaignDdl = $('#campaignDdl');
   var selCampID = $campaignDdl.val();
   var url = $campaignDdl.data('url');
   $('#campaign').load(url + "/" + selCampID));
})
```

Comment: Oh gosh, ofcourse. I can simply call the Action again. That wasn't very smart of me. Thanks! And i' ll use the load function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just mimic the onchange function for a jquery.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('Template knop geklikt');
    var $campaignDdl = $('#campaignDdl');
    var selCampID = $campaignDdl.val();
    var url = $campaignDdl.data('url');
    $.post(url, { selectedCampaignID: selCampID }, function (data) {
        $('#campaign').html(data);
    })
});
```

This should do the exact same thing as when the ddl changes, but instead take the value that is already selected and put the corresponding view in the div.

Comment: Yes indeed. You are right. D'oh on me. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just call the change method in order to not duplicate code, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('#campaignDdl').change(function () {
        //alert('Template knop geklikt');
        var $campaignDdl = $('#campaignDdl');
        var selCampID = $campaignDdl.val();
        var url = $campaignDdl.data('url');
        $.post(url, { selectedCampaignID: selCampID }, function (data) {
            $('#campaign').html(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr) { 
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqxhr)); 
    })
    .change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('Template knop geklikt');
    var $campaignDdl = $('#campaignDdl');
    var selCampID = $campaignDdl.val();
    var url = $campaignDdl.data('url');
    $.post(url, { selectedCampaignID: selCampID }, function (data) {
    $('#campaign').html('');            
    $('#campaign').append(data.Data);
        })
    })
```

;

Comment: Thanks, you're right ofcourse. Just call the Action again on a reload. D'oh.